# Proof reading that if $E$ be a Banach space and $T : E \to \Bbb K$ a linear map, then $T$ is continuous iff $\ker(T)$ is a closed subspace of $E$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and $T : E \to \Bbb K$ a linear map. Show that $T$ is continuous iff $\ker(T)$ is a closed linear subspace of $E$. (Hint: Suppose that $T$ is not continuous at $0 \in E$ and show that $\ker(T)$ is not closed.)

The first direction follows from $\ker(T) = T^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $\{0\}$ being closed.

For the second direction the proof I read is as follows. Suppose that $T$ is not continuous at $0$, then for all $n$ there exists a unit vector $x_n$ such that $|Tx_n| \ge n$. Set $y_n = x_n/Tx_n$ and notice that $Ty_n=1$ for all $n$. Now $z_n = y_1-y_n \in \ker(T)$ for all $n$. Also $\|y_n\| \le 1/n$ so $z_n \to y_1$, but $y_1 \notin \ker(T)$. This implies that there exists a sequence $z_n$ in a closed subspace for which the limit is not contained in it which is a contradiction. Therefore $T$ must be continuous.

---

There are some very counterinutivite ideas here. How do they derive from $T$ not being continuous at $0$ that for all $n$ there exists a unit vector $x_n$ for which $|Tx_n| \ge n$? This feels like it's coming from thin air here.

Answer (score 2):

Continuity at $0$ the linear operator $T:E\to \mathbb{K}$ over Banach spaces is equivalent to being continuous (everywhere) and also to being bounded in the sense that
$$
\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|<\infty.
$$

So, stating that it is not continuous at $0$ is equivalent to stating that the supremum is $\infty$. This is to say that there must be a sequence  $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|Tx_n\|\geq n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

In case you are working with a different definition of boundedness, recall that
$$\sup_{\|x\|<1} \|Tx\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \|Tx\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|=\sup_{\|x\|\neq 0} \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$$

Comment: So $T$ not being continuous implies that $\|T\|$ is also unbounded? I.e. $\|Tx\|_\infty = \infty$? I wonder where does this condition that $\|x_n\| = 1$ come from? @n-pullbacki

Comment: That $T$ is not continuous is equivalent to not being bounded (over the unit ball or sphere). As any linear operator verifies $\|T\lambda x\|=\lambda\|Tx\|\xrightarrow{}{\lambda\to \infty}\infty$ for any fixed $x$ and scalar $\lambda$ such that $Tx\neq 0$, It doesn't make much sense asking it to be bounded over the whole space, for this would imply that $T=0$. This is the reason one needs only to ask it to be bounded on the unit ball (or any other ball centered at $0$ for that matter).